# Jquery - Pass $(this) to callback function without var

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello to the wonderful community !

I have a problem in jquery regarding the access to the $(this) inside a function. Usually i would have used a var to pass it through, but in the actual case i can't define any var.

And i don't know how to pass it through the parameters of "source: function()".

I tried "source: function(request, response, self = $(this))" but it doesn't work.

```
$(".autocomplete-file-label").autocomplete({
  minLength: 3,
  source: function(request, response){
    var category = $(this).attr("data-category");
    if(category == '')
    {
      var source = 'http://www.example.com/?term=' + request.term;
    }
    else
    {
      var source = 'http://www.example.com/?term=' + request.term + '&type=' + category;
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: source,
      data : request.term,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data) 
      {
        response($.map(data, function( item ) {
          return item;
        }));
      }
    });

  },
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
   $(this).val( ui.item.label );
   return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
   $(this).val( ui.item.label);
   $(this).next(".autocomplete-file-id").val( ui.item.id );
   return false;
  }
})
```

If you have any solution, i will be veryyyyy happy !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is `$(this)` refers to? what exactly you want to achieve and can you post your html here?

Comment: wich library do you use it ?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar $(this) refers to $(".autocomplete-file-label")

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach for plugins that you need instance specific data from element is to  initiate the plugin inside an `each` loop

```
$(".autocomplete-file-label").each(function() {
  var category = $(this).attr("data-category");

  $(this).autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: function(request, response) {

        if (category == ''){
           ///.....
        }
      }
      //....
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, it sounds perfect to me ! Thanks, i didn't think about that way !!!! You saved me !!! <3